# Workshopping my question about Armor Class ranges

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, workshop-question

I posted this question: [Which Armor Class values should be used as Controls when making Damage Calculations?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142032/42386) in an attempt to try to reify the Armor Class values I use when making DPR calculations for this stack. It was closed for being too opinion based, and I'd like to know what an answerable version of this question would be.

My assumption is that the experience of stack users who've played a lot more campaigns than I have (which isn't a lot, FYI) might shed some light on which AC values are more commonly used by DMs and (possibly especially) published campaigns; information which wouldn't necessarily be gleaned from simply reading each statblock in the Monster Manual. But at the same time, I think there's ways to discern between bad answers to this question and good answers, and if not, then what should be done with the question to get to that point?

Comment: IMO there is nothing wrong with the question as written. Possibly add "good subjective" and protect the question so only experienced users can answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ask about the statistical distribution of AC values. Even a change as simple as "what is the average AC of monsters at each CR" will eliminate answers that draw a conclusion without putting in the work you care about. As it is, you're likely to get answers along the lines of "AC 16 at CR 8 cos that's what the DMG says" or even "I've DMed a lot and I feel like it's 12".

That said, you probably shouldn't ask the actual question "what is the average AC of monsters at each CR", because it's liable to be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95624/15469).

Answer (score 2):

I had commented on this question asking for clarification on why CR is involved at all. If you're asking about a baseline AC, I do not see why CR is part of this. If you focus just on that baseline AC request, I don't see any issue why this can't be reopened (but do see a potential issue with opinion-based answers, but that's something to deal with if and when it happens.)

Comment: AC doesn't go up because of CR, but CR might go up because of high AC. To get the answer you need to look at published adventures and average out the ACs of all creatures.